# Setting images in a grid layout to change on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a grid layout of 4 photos and I need to set them to change when hovered over.

I am able to do this with one image using 'img:hover' and 'position: absolute;' however with multiple images, absolute positioning messes up the layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSV7Xfy9xsIHJKQDzyNeuADyO-dTfLioo221t2-7m8ABCWDiaJKTQ" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSV7Xfy9xsIHJKQDzyNeuADyO-dTfLioo221t2-7m8ABCWDiaJKTQ" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code that I have so far and I have tried adding background(url...) in the CSS to no avail.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    <img class="hover-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdf7iabWlo2C3SXNzPOVitkY47gwvZXSkYXRt9Xh0vdRFcbMA5" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="hover-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdf7iabWlo2C3SXNzPOVitkY47gwvZXSkYXRt9Xh0vdRFcbMA5" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
     <img class="hover-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdf7iabWlo2C3SXNzPOVitkY47gwvZXSkYXRt9Xh0vdRFcbMA5" />
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/956981/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956981.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
     <img class="hover-img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdf7iabWlo2C3SXNzPOVitkY47gwvZXSkYXRt9Xh0vdRFcbMA5" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.hover-img{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.column:hover img + img{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/jhrpfq8u/4/

Comment: This works but I can't seem to find a way to ensure that the hover image remains the same size? At the moment it gets slightly larger even though the width is set to 100%...

Comment: Scrap that, the 5px padding just needed to be added to the hover image too. Many thanks Lalji for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Overlay using css. Please check this .. It will work for you**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/download-2.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">111<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/cloudflare.png" alt="Avatar" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/download-2.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">222<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/cloudflare.png" alt="Avatar" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/download-2.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">333<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/cloudflare.png" alt="Avatar" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/16/000000/download-2.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">444<img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/cloudflare.png" alt="Avatar" class="image"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the code suggested by Lalji above so that the style was applied to the images accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding: 20px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background: #f2f2f2;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
      grid-gap: 1em;
    }
    /* hover styles */
    
    .location-listing {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .location-image {
      line-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .location-image img {
      filter: blur(0px);
      transition: filter 0.3s ease-in;
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .location-title {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity .5s;
      background: rgba(90, 0, 10, 0.4);
      color: white;
      /* position the text in t’ middle*/
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .location-title:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .location-listing:hover .location-title {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .location-listing:hover .location-image img {
      filter: blur(2px);
    }
    /* for touch screen devices */
    
    @media (hover: none) {
      .location-title {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      .location-image img {
        filter: blur(2px);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child-page-listing">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <article id="3685" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">San Francisco</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/san-fransisco-768x432.jpg" alt="san francisco"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article id="3688" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">London</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/london-768x432.jpg" alt="london"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article id="3691" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">New York</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/new-york-768x432.jpg" alt="new york"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article id="3694" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">Cape Town</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/cape-town-768x432.jpg" alt="cape town"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article id="3697" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">Beijing</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/beijing-768x432.jpg" alt="beijing"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article id="3700" class="location-listing">
          <a class="location-title" href="#">Paris</a>
          <div class="location-image">
            <a href="#"><img width="300" height="169" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/210284/paris-768x432.jpg" alt="paris"></a>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- end grid container -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```